# MVVM WPF ViewModel DispatcherTimer not updating view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a DispatcherTimer in my ViewModel that i can see firing every interval, but the view is not being updated?

the feed data comes from a xml url and i am trying to refresh the form every x seconds. Maybe more or less lables / differnt status

heres the code snippets:

ViewModel.cs

```
public class Nodes
{
public string name { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public string status { get; set; }
public string last { get; set; }
public int level { get; set; }
public string parent { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<CI> CIs
{
get;
set;
}

DispatcherTimer LogTimer;

public void LoadCIs()
{
ObservableCollection<CI> cis = new ObservableCollection<CI>();

LogTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
LogTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);

LogTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
    //pull node list
    List<Nodes> SortedList = PopulateNodes();

    foreach (Nodes Node in SortedList)
    {
        //create labels for all top level nodes
        if (Node.level == 3)
        {
            cis.Add(new CI { NodeName = Node.name, NodeStatus = Node.status });
        }
    }

    CIs = cis;

};

LogTimer.Start();

}
```

Model.cs

```
public class CI : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  private string nodeName;
  private string nodeStatus;

    public string NodeName { 
     get { 
        return nodeName; 
     }

     set { 
        if (nodeName != value) { 
           nodeName = value; 
           RaisePropertyChanged("NodeName"); 
        } 
     } 
  }

    public string NodeStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return nodeStatus;
        }

        set
        {
            if (nodeStatus != value)
            {
                nodeStatus = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("NodeStatus");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property) {
     if (PropertyChanged != null) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
     } 
  } 
   }
```

view.xaml

```
<Grid> 
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Path = CIs}">

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Label Content = "{Binding Path = NodeName, Mode = OneWay}" 
                        Background = "{Binding Path = NodeStatus, Mode = OneWay}" 
                        Foreground="White"
                        FontFamily="Arial Black"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"                            
                        BorderBrush="Black" 
                        BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"/>

                </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

how the form should look without timer enabled / commented out:

[image]

with the timer code enabled nothing is added to grid:

[image]

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem:**

You are changing the Collection `CIs` but do not notify it is changed. [ObservableCollections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) report their changes but you're overwriting it, it will not report that.

---

**Option 1:**

Because you use an `ObservableCollection` you can add it to the bound collection directly and it will notify the UI automatically. 
So instead of:

```
cis.Add(new CI { NodeName = Node.name, NodeStatus = Node.status });
```

Do this:

```
CIs.Add(new CI { NodeName = Node.name, NodeStatus = Node.status });
```

if you do this you have to initialize `CIs` first:

```
public ObservableCollection<CI> CIs
{
    get;
    set;
} = new ObservableCollection<CI>(); // < initialize it
```

---

**Option 2:**

Add the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface to the Nodes class and notify like this:

`this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( nameof( this.CIs ) ) );`

in the setter of `CIs`

Comment: with Option 1: i get 'System.NullReferenceException'  Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on the CIs.Add ?

Comment: @DwayneDibbley CIs isn't a collection yet. Assign an empty observable collection to it in the constructor of the class or like how I show above (added it to Option 1 for you)

Comment: Thanks that works however the CIs and cis collections are growing each loop, would i need to set something unique to each label so it knows they are the same?

Comment: Just remove the cis collection. It is not needed anymore (you can use CIs for everything now). If my answer answered your question would you mind accepting it? :)

Comment: Ive removed the cis collection, but the CIs i just being appended to each loop with another set do i need to either clear the CIs collection each loop? or maybe look at option 2 ( i have an inotifypropertychanged in the model class? ) Thanks

Comment: @DwayneDibbley Do you want to clear it each time? You could just put a `CIs.Clear()` before the foreach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189455/discussion-between-dwayne-dibbley-and-epickip).